# MySQLのトランザクション管理について

Tags: java, mysql, spring

現在、AWSを6つ用いて、クローラーを稼働させています。
その6サーバーそれぞれで別々のクローラー(マルチスレッドマルチプロセス)が動いていますが、DBサーバー(InnoDB)は1つで、
並列に書き込み、読み込みを行っています。

そのせいか、すべてのサーバーのクローラーで、毎日数件から数十件下記のようなエラーが発生します。
※諸事情により、全文記載できません。

```
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed!
```

この例外を見るに、トランザクションが開始されていないように見えます。
ですが、springに自動で管理させているということもあるので、(アプリケーション側の)トランザクション管理にバグがあるというわけでもありません。

とすると、やはり並列にアクセスするため、プロセス間の排他制御ができていないのが原因なのでしょうか？
一応、synchronizedはしているので、マルチスレッドの排他制御はできています。

この問題について、なにかいい解決策をご存じの方はいらっしゃいませんか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

---

先日、`idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes=10`を追加して同じように動かしたところ、
上記エラーだけではなく、テーブルロックの例外も発生するようになってしまいました。
今までは半年以上発生していなかったエラーなので、この設定はだめみたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Connection is closed!`が出ているので、poolしてるconnectionが死んでいて、そいつを使おうとしているのではないですか?
`validationQuery`に`select 1`とか設定しておくと解決できるのではないでしょうか

Comment: 申し遅れましたが、現在接続設定にはBoneCPを使用しているので、
今の設定`idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes=10`の間隔をもっと短くすることしかできません。
これでも大丈夫でしょうか？

Comment: BoneCPをちゃんと使ったことがないのとソースを追いかけていませんので、ごめんなさい確信はありません。が、同様の結果を得られるかも知れませんね。 maven centralに登録されているバージョンが最新ではないようなので、0.8.0をお使いであれば、 https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/jolbox/bonecp/0.8.1-SNAPSHOT/ 0.8.1を試してみることも解決につながるかも知れません

Comment: ありがとうございます。とりあえず今試験的に設定してみました。再発するようであればまた調べてみます。

Answer (score 1):

mysqlのエラーログを参照してみてはいかがでしょうか？java側のエラーでは真の原因がわからないことがあります。実はなんらかの原因で密かにmysqlが再起動していて接続が切れるなんてこともあります。